# Simple Local Proxy vb.net

Tags: vb.net, proxy, local

I made a proxy application to test.

I am using TCP Listener.

After accepting bytes(request) what should I do.

Can I send these bytes using webclient?

```
Module MyTcpListener
Sub Main()
    Task.Run(Sub()
                 Dim server As Sockets.TcpListener
                 server = Nothing
                 Try
                     Dim port As Int32 = 8080
                     Dim localAddr As IPAddress = IPAddress.Any
                     server = New Sockets.TcpListener(localAddr, port)
                     server.Start()
                     Do
                         Dim data = server.AcceptTcpClient()
                         Dim bytes(data.ReceiveBufferSize - 1) As Byte
                         data.Client.Receive(bytes)
                         'Here how can i send abytes using webclient or tcpclient
                         data.Close()
                     Loop
                 Catch ex As Exception

                 End Try
             End Sub)
    Do
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
    Loop
End Sub
End Module
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you have the sub in your MainSub? Why do you have a `Try-Catch-End Try` with nothing to handle exceptions in the `Catch`? If you want a Proxy for the WebClient you already have a [built-in function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.proxy(v=vs.110).aspx) for that.

Comment: I used multi-threading.
I only watch what is being going on net.